# ARKIT camera is not tracking state after initialization

Tags: ios, swift, arkit, ios16

After upgrading iPhone to the iOS version 16, ARKit having issue with ARSession CameraTrackingState. TrackingState is going to .notAvailable and .limited(initializing) state and never returning to tracking state .normal. Screen camera keep showing loading. And when I am turning camera on and off , it shows the AR model on the screen.

> Tested Device: iPhone 12 Pro Max with iOS version 16.0.

For iOS 15.6, TrackingState is going to .notAvailable and .limited(initializing) state and .limited(relocalising) and then .normal. Relocalization state is also handled whenever it going to the interruption.

```
func sessionShouldAttemptRelocalization(_ session: ARSession) -> Bool {

    let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()

    configuration.planeDetection = [.horizontal,.vertical]

    session.run(configuration, options: [.resetTracking, .removeExistingAnchors])

    return true

  }
```

Please suggest some solution as I am not able to debug this. Is there any upgrade or issue with iOS version 16?

Comment: From where did you call the function sessionShouldAttemptRelocalization()?

Comment: Sessionshouldattemptrelocaluzation is called when arsession is interrupted, where i am just reseting the session.

Comment: did you start the session from viewdidload?

Comment: Starting the session in viewWillAppear